# Why sudo apt-get update is giving confusing output?

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for the last few years. Every time I run an update before installing any new software. But since yesterday whenever I run update it prints in the terminal below:

```
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Err:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/deb testing/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.18.14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/deb testing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 172.217.18.14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Does anyone know how-how to fix these issues?

Comment: Remove that `http://dl.google.com/linux/deb testing/non-free` repository.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software

and remove that `http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages` repository from software sources.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I just applied what Pilot6 suggested. It is almost OK, except Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Comment: That is 100% OK. It means that there is nothing new in the Chrome repo.

Comment: Thanks again you guys are outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (or in some `*.list` file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`).

For Google Chrome it should be:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

For Google Earth:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/ stable main
```

Remove the problematic line `http://dl.google.com/linux/deb testing` or change to one of the above by hand or with *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) on *Other Software* tab.